# function LOOKUP() don´t return result expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to use lookup function with a simple list of text, but in one sheet in my pc is not function,i write `=LOOKUP("Zapatilla 4",A28:A34)` in the table

| description | other info |
| --- | --- |
| Zapatilla 1 | disponible |
| Zapatilla 2 | disponible |
| Zapatilla 3 | agotado |
| Zapatilla 4 | disponible |

I don´t understand why in otre pc this its return the correct

[image]

Comment: Could there be spaces after the values in the first pic?

Comment: Your formula refers to A28:A34 but in first screenshot the data is in Column B at B28:B34

Answer (score 0):

##### #N/A Error

Excel's *Help on this Error*:

> The **#N/A** error generally indicates that a formula can’t find what it’s been asked to look for.

> The most common cause of the #N/A error is with XLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, LOOKUP, or MATCH functions if a formula can’t find a referenced value. For example, your lookup value doesn’t exist in the source data.

> Either ***make sure that the lookup value exists*** in the source data, or use an error handler such as IFERROR in the formula. For example, =IFERROR(FORMULA(),0)

##### Investigating Error Messages

I approach solving error messages by first assuming that the error message is correct and informative. While that is not always the case, the outliers are typically rounding errors.

Excel thinks that the search string cannot be matched in the range.  You can problem solve using some simple tests such as the ones that follow or one of your own creation to isolate the problem source:

- Copy the search string from the formula and insert it into your range (or replace the existing value).  Is the value now found?
- check the length of the search string and compare to the length of the value in the range

```
=IF(
    LEN("Zapatilla 4")-LEN(B31)<>0,
       "Strings are DIFFERENT",
       "Strings MAY be different but are SAME LENGTH"
 )
```

- SUBSTITUTE for a unique string (one or more characters that don't match existing strings)

```
=IF(
    SUBSTITUTE(B11,"Zapatilla 4","")="",
    "Strings are IDENTICAL",
    "Strings are DIFFERENT"
 )
```

Once you confirm they are different - #N/A error in addition to results of your test(s) - you will then quickly be able to figure out ***what*** is different, and then the ***why*** will dictate how you address it.

- Read more from Microsoft:
  [How to correct a #N/A error in the VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-n-a-error-in-the-vlookup-function-e037d763-ffc3-4fae-a909-89c482d389b2)

<kbd>**How to correct a #N/A error**   *(Excel In-App Help)*</kbd>
[image: How to correct a #N/A error]